# Top and Bottom 5% elements from data stream

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a digital input stream,
The average value of the last last k value is required, and in the calculation,
it is required to remove top5% and bottom5% of the k numbers.

Can we do it in linear time. A O(n log k) solution would be through using priority queues but I am not able to think of a more optimal solution.

Comment: Since you must retain the a sorted version of the *entire* input stream to track the top and bottom 5% you sort of stuck with O(n log n) solution (i.e., log(n) insertion into sorted input structure).

Comment: do you want to calculate `n` average numbers in less than `O(n log k)` time?

Comment: @Yola I think you need to retain all `n` values since you need to remember them to know the new ranking for every new input value. e.g., you always have to remember the very first value because it may fall in and out of the top/bottom 5% at any point in the future.

Comment: @wcochran you need to remember 5% only for `k` not for `n` I think.

Comment: @Yola I think you are correct ... since all the stats are for the last `k` numbers we can forget about the ones that came before that. So you want to purge the oldest number and add the newest number to retain `k` values.

Comment: You could use two data structure: a *deque* to hold the last `k` values in the order they are given and an *ordered tree* to maintain a sorted version of the last `k` values. For each new value purge the oldest value (value at head of deque) from both data structures, and add the new value to each data structure. Use the ordered tree to perform the proper statistic on the current `k` values. Insert/delete from deque is O(1) and insert/delete from tree is O(log k). Result is O(n log k).

Answer (score 1):

Here is `O(n log(k))` approach. I used a *deque* to hold the last `k` values in input order and a *ordered set* to maintain a sorted version of the last `k` values:

```
deque<T> d;
set<T> s;   // e.g., red-black tree
for each new value x {
     d.push_back(x);
     s.insert(x);
     if (d.size() > k) {
         old = d.front(); d.pop_front();
         s.erase(old);
         // s holds sorted k-values
         // traverse to find mean
         // traverse in order, pass over the first and last 0.05*k values
     }
}
```